# Disproving: If $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, then there exists $c > 0$ such that $f(x)\geq c$ for all $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, then there exists $c > 0$ such that $f(x)\geq c$ for all $x$.

I know this is a false statement, since I can use $f(x)=e^{-x}$. The problem is, I'm unsure of how to prove this is the case.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you can't establish that $e^{-x}$ is a counterexample? If so, try this: Pick any $c >0$. For $x > -\ln c, e^{-x} < c$. Thus, for every $c>0$, this gives a range of $x \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the proposition is violated, and hence it is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your example $f(x) = e^{-x}$, assume there exists some $c > 0$ such that $f(x) \geq c$ for all $x$. You want to get a contradiction by showing there exists some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $e^{-x} < c$. So just solve this inequality and you will get your desired $x$.

Comment: "there exists some $x \in \mathbb{R}$" doesn't my $x$ need to be in $[0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with the exponential map, perhaps you can just use $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & (0\leq x<1) \\
\frac{1}{x} & (x\geq 1)
\end{cases}$$
and one version of the Archimedes' principle saying that $(\forall)\epsilon>0, (\exists)N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\epsilon$.

Thank @MC989 who pointed out my previous mistake.

Comment: The main problem with this function is that it isn't defined at $x=0$

Comment: @MC989 Ops. Thanks for your remind. That was a careless mistake. I will change it.